# cannot redirect pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

what i really need is to redirect this link in my joomla site http://www.hibasfood.com/index.php/food/1704-2012--00-57-38/13312-2012--08-43-08

to this link  http://www.hibasfood.com/index.php/food/17-2012-04-20-00-57-38/133-2012-12-28-08-43-08

how shall i do this using 301 in joomla ?!

p.s i dont have .htaccess file in my joomla folder , but i do have htaccess.txt !

Comment: Check [this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=331912) and [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/url-redirection) and [this](http://www.hosting.com/support/joomla/create-a-url-redirect-in-joomla).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your root .htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301  http://www.hibasfood.com/index.php/food/1704-2012--00-57-38/13312-2012--08-43-08    http://www.hibasfood.com/index.php/food/17-2012-04-20-00-57-38/133-2012-12-28-08-43-08
```

EG:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.yourdomain.com/oldpage.html  http://www.yourdomain.com/newpage.html
```